# Alpine.js x-bind not applying after an HTMX swap

Tags: django, alpine.js, htmx

I have an element that is in the initial page load and updates after form post through an HTMX out of bounds swap. On initial load the x-bind formats as expected. After the swap the values from the swapped element display as expected using x-text. The x-bind always fails to apply the formatting that should trigger when staffCount < shiftNeed. When it should apply it quickly flickers immediately after the swap but then goes away. Same flicker is not present when it should not apply.

Element on initial page load

```
<tr x-data="{ shiftNeed: {{ day_need }} }">
    <td class="fw-bold">Day</td>
    <td class="fw-bold text-center" x-text="shiftNeed"></td>
    {% for i, val in day_list|zip:day_staffing %}
    <td>
        <div id="dayCount{{ i }}"
             x-data="{ staffCount: {{ val }} }"
             x-text="staffCount"
             x-bind:class="{ 'bg-danger': staffCount < shiftNeed }"
        ></div>
     </td>
     {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Partial template swapped in

```
{% include "schedule/components/schedule_shift_button.html" %}
<div
    id="{{ shift.time_of_day_label|lower }}Count{{ shift.day_num }}" 
    class="text-center rounded"
    hx-swap-oob="true"
    x-data="{ staffCount: {{ shift.staff_count }}}"
    x-text="staffCount"
    x-init="console.log(staffCount < shiftNeed)"
    x-bind:class="{ 'bg-danger': staffCount < shiftNeed }"
></div>
```

I added logging statements on the x-init to inspect output, console always displays the expected values of staffCount and shiftNeed and evaluates the criteria used in the x-bind as expected.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I have no idea why but removing the element id worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried this : https://htmx.org/extensions/alpine-morph/